# Extracting the coefficients of each model by using a series of map functions

Tags: r, statistics

I am creating the following model:

```
models <- mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map(function(df) lm(mpg ~ wt, data = df))
```

Based on the results you get from that, I am trying to extract the coefficients by using a series of map functions.

The results *should* look like this:

```
       4          6        8
-5.647025 -2.780106 -2.192438
```

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If one of the answers below solves your  problem, you're encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map_dbl` with the `coef` function to pick out the "wt" coefficients:

```
coefs <- mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map(function(df) lm(mpg ~ wt, data = df)) %>%
  map_dbl(~coef(.)[["wt"]])
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like

```r
coefs <- (mtcars 
  %>% split(.$cyl) 
  %>% map(lm, formula = mpg~wt) 
  %>% map_dbl(~coef(.)[["wt"]])
)
```

should do what you want? If you want to get more information, ending with `map_dfr(broom::tidy)` instead of the `map_dbl` will be helpful (you can use the `.id=` argument too, although this is less useful when the list doesn't have named arguments).

This is very similar to @henryn's answer, although the `map` syntax (using the named `formula` argument means that the data get substituted as the *next* argument implicitly, so you don't have to use an anonymous function `function(df) lm(mpg ~ wt, data = df)` or (with R >= 4.1.0) `\(df) lm(mpg ~ wt, data = df)`: I think the usual way of doing this, `~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)` *might* get messed up by the tilde in the formula, but I'm nto sure ...

Comment: Upvoting - I actually prefer `map(lm, formula = mpg~wt)` to my answer, it is much cleaner (I somewhat thoughtlessly took what the OP had already done and piped into `map_dbl`)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% map(function(x) {
                                           c = lm(mpg ~ wt, data = x)
                                           c$coefficients[2]
                                             }) %>% unlist
     4.wt      6.wt      8.wt 
-5.647025 -2.780106 -2.192438
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** This could be done in straight dplyr:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(wt = coef(lm(mpg ~ wt))[[2]], .groups = "drop")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl    wt
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4 -5.65
2     6 -2.78
3     8 -2.19
```

**2)** This variation also works:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(wt = cov(mpg, wt) / var(wt), .groups = "drop")
```

**3)** Also consider this -- omit the [2] to get both coefficients.

```
library(nlme)
coef(lmList(mpg ~ wt | cyl, mtcars))[2]
```

giving:

```
         wt
4 -5.647025
6 -2.780106
8 -2.192438
```